# Unable to use specific compiler in cmake created CodeBlocks project

Tags: cmake, codeblocks

I have various projects that I need to compile them with different compilers.

So, what I need is an IDE that lets easily allow me to choose/change a target and compile projects for that target.

Another need is to use **cmake**.

I am now trying **CodeBlocks** in windows. First I try to add a compiler:

- I have set:

  Settings->Toolchain executables->Compiler's installation directory->Program Files
- Then I create CodeBlocks project with **cmake -G "CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles"**
- I open the project in CodeBlocks that is generated by cmake.
- I chose compiler in Project Settings.
- I build.
- Then I discover that compiler in Project Settings is totally ignored! Because it is used the one in CMakeCache.
- Thus, I write a script that first set CC and CXX, then run cmake.
- With this way I see that CMakeCache has the compiler that I want.
- Then I build the project in CodeBlocks.
- Now, for g++.exe, the correct compiler is used. However, CodeBlocks insists and insists again to use default MinGW compiler (which is in path) for **mingw32-make.exe**

Here is the last build output, where `D:/Qt/Qt5.4.1/Tools/mingw491_32/bin` is default and `C:\mingw_x86_64\release7.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v5-rev2.7\bin` is the correct one.

```
-------------- Build: 32bit in deneme21 (compiler: MinGW GCC Compiler 32bit)---------------

Checking if target is up-to-date: mingw32-make.exe -q -f Makefile 32bit
Running command: D:/Qt/Qt5.4.1/Tools/mingw491_32/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f "D:/Qt_ws/deneme/deneme31/Makefile"  VERBOSE=1 install/strip
C:\CMake3.10.2\win32\bin\cmake.exe -HD:\Qt_ws\deneme\deneme31 -BD:\Qt_ws\deneme\deneme31 --check-build-system CMakeFiles\Makefile.cmake 0
C:\CMake3.10.2\win32\bin\cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_start D:\Qt_ws\deneme\deneme31\CMakeFiles D:\Qt_ws\deneme\deneme31\CMakeFiles\progress.marks
D:/Qt/Qt5.4.1/Tools/mingw491_32/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f CMakeFiles\Makefile2 all
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory 'D:/Qt_ws/deneme/deneme31'
D:/Qt/Qt5.4.1/Tools/mingw491_32/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f CMakeFiles\deneme21.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/deneme21.dir/depend
mingw32-make.exe[2]: Entering directory 'D:/Qt_ws/deneme/deneme31'
C:\CMake3.10.2\win32\bin\cmake.exe -E cmake_depends "MinGW Makefiles" D:\Qt_ws\deneme\deneme31 D:\Qt_ws\deneme\deneme31 D:\Qt_ws\deneme\deneme31 D:\Qt_ws\deneme\deneme31 D:\Qt_ws\deneme\deneme31\CMakeFiles\deneme21.dir\DependInfo.cmake --color=
mingw32-make.exe[2]: Leaving directory 'D:/Qt_ws/deneme/deneme31'
D:/Qt/Qt5.4.1/Tools/mingw491_32/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f CMakeFiles\deneme21.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/deneme21.dir/build
mingw32-make.exe[2]: Entering directory 'D:/Qt_ws/deneme/deneme31'
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/deneme21.dir/src/foo.cpp.obj
C:\mingw_x86_64\release7.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v5-rev2.7\bin\g++.exe   @CMakeFiles/deneme21.dir/includes_CXX.rsp -m32   -o CMakeFiles\deneme21.dir\src\foo.cpp.obj -c D:\Qt_ws\deneme\deneme31\src\foo.cpp
[100%] Linking CXX static library libdeneme21.a
C:\CMake3.10.2\win32\bin\cmake.exe -P CMakeFiles\deneme21.dir\cmake_clean_target.cmake
C:\CMake3.10.2\win32\bin\cmake.exe -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles\deneme21.dir\link.txt --verbose=1
C:\mingw_x86_64\release7.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v5-rev2.7\bin\ar.exe qc libdeneme21.a  CMakeFiles/deneme21.dir/src/foo.cpp.obj
C:\mingw_x86_64\release7.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v5-rev2.7\bin\ranlib.exe libdeneme21.a
mingw32-make.exe[2]: Leaving directory 'D:/Qt_ws/deneme/deneme31'
[100%] Built target deneme21
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory 'D:/Qt_ws/deneme/deneme31'
C:\CMake3.10.2\win32\bin\cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_start D:\Qt_ws\deneme\deneme31\CMakeFiles 0
D:/Qt/Qt5.4.1/Tools/mingw491_32/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f CMakeFiles\Makefile2 preinstall
```

How can I make CodeBlocks use the compiler that I want in cmake created project?

Comment: When you mentioned the cache, it made me think that you didn't delete your cmake configuration.  cmake stores your previously selected generator in the cache.  This will not be refreshed if you run cmake again.  Try deleting your cmake cache (or deleting the entire build directory) and running cmake again with the "-G" parameter.

Comment: But then we lose build options that we have chosen. What I need is this: To have 2 compilers: 32bit and 64bit. Choose one of them. Compile. That's it! But the problems I saw that: cmake generate CodeBlocks project file. Well! But it embeds compiler path in that project file! With a workaround I can edit it, let say OK. But what about CMakeCache.txt? Because compiler path is also embedded there! With every distinct compiler do I need different CMakeCache.txt? With a pre-build script I can choose one but this is the same to keep distinct project for every compiler. Any idea?

Comment: cmake is a single-configuration tool; for each compiler, (or each debug/release config), you'd want an independant build directory.  Each has its own cache.  So yes: you need a different cache for each compiler.  I don't know code-blocks well, but I know qtCreator, kDevelop, and vs code.  For each of those IDEs, you have the option of defining your cmake parameters before you generate the cache.  Note that with cmake, the choice of compiler/environment is always left to the user.  If they just download the sources and configure, they'll get defaults relevant to their environment which is good.

Comment: If you want to pursuade your users to use a specific config, use [options](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/option.html) and set the defaults to what you'd like.  Then they'd get that config unless they explicitly change it.